# Azure Devops Get package Workitem state

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm creating a package work Item using Powershell script in Azure Devops workitem and updating the same on successful completion of deployment as Completed.

Question:
How do i Query the package state?
I tried using the below powershell, which queries the exisitng package but unable to find the logic to get system.state of the package

My Powershell:

```
function TestState{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]
    $package,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]
    $secret,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]
    $DevopsProject

)
$header = prepareHeader $secret
$query = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '$DevopsProject' AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Package' AND [System.Title] = '$PackageName' "
$json = @{ query = $query }
$jsonBody = ConvertTo-Json $json
$url  = "http://10.0.0.5/Test/$DevopsProject/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.0"
$output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -Body $jsonbody
$testurl = $output.workitems.url
$testurl = $testurl.Split('')
$test_url = $testurl[0]+'?api-version=6.0'
$output1 = Invoke-webrequest -uri "$test_url" -useBaseParsing -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header | ConvertFrom-json
return $output1
}
```

My Pipeline:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        $test = checkPackagestate "$PackageName" "$(secret)" $(DevopsProject)"
```

Comment: PS: not sure what secret is, but if that's a PAT, then you can replace it with `env: secret: $(system.accesstoken)` as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may update your script to this version

```
function TestState{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]
    $package,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]
    $secret,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]
    $DevopsProject

)
$header = prepareHeader $secret
$query = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '$DevopsProject' AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Package' AND [System.Title] = '$PackageName' "
$json = @{ query = $query }
$jsonBody = ConvertTo-Json $json
$url  = "http://10.0.0.5/Test/$DevopsProject/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.0"
$output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -Body $jsonbody

$outputres = ""

foreach ($wi in $output.workitems)
{
  $test_url = $wi.url +'?api-version=6.0'
  $output1 = Invoke-webrequest -uri "$test_url" -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header | ConvertFrom-json
  $outputres += "$($output1.id) : $($output1.fields.'System.Title') : $($output1.fields.'System.State')`n"
}    

return $outputres
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using just a query: [Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)
It returns the set of workitems ids:

```
{
  "queryType": "flat",
  "asOf": "2014-12-29T20:49:34.617Z",
  "columns": [
    {
      "referenceName": "System.Id",
      ....
    },
    ...
  ],
  "sortColumns": [
    {
      "field": {
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority",
        ....
      },
      "descending": false
    },
    ...
  ],
  "workItems": [
    {
      "id": 300,
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/300"
    },
    {
      "id": 299,
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/299"
    },
    {
      "id": 298,
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/298"
    },
    .....
  ]
}
```

Then you have to use each `id` to get workitem details: [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

or use `url` under id

Comment: Basically it already provides the URL for each work item to fetch the details. You can pass in which fields you want in case you don't need all of them.

Comment: @jessehouwing yes, you are right

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I understand where to get the system.state now. I modified the script and its not working. Any suggestion please.

Comment: What's not working? Any error? It looks like you are trying to read the Url property of the work items array. But you probably want to take the first item from that array, so `testurl = $output.workItems[0].url`. Also check casing of `Items`, it may matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShamraiAleksander, jessehouwing. Its working fine.